# Move from android after intially declining

Tags: iphone, ios, android

I have a blank Iphone 6 I am moving to. Upon initially setting up the iphone, it asked me if I want to move over from Android. I initially declined, thinking I could access this feature later. But now I can not find out how to access it.

Can I still run the "Move from android" operation, after I initially declined it, and completed the rest of the setup process?

Comment: Do a factory reset and start again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wipe the phone to get the assistant to run. It won’t merge content, just import on to a blank device.  Make a backup if you want and then in settings, erase all content and settings. Then you can run the Android import and get all the migration done and review.

Worst case, you examine the data, sync or export contacts and apps and then erase / restore your current backup and merge the data.